# Why mongodb's find() method is not able to find the recently inserted document in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongodb-query

```js
for (let obj in objects) {
    blabla.find({
        'url': obj.urlObj.url
    }).toArray((err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return err
        }

        if (results.length === 0) {
            blabla.insert({
                url: obj.urlObj.url,
                views: 1
            })
        } else {
            blabla.update({
                _id: results[0]._id
            }, {
                $inc: {
                    views: 1
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

This piece of code is under a loop where I get `obj`, now I'm trying to find a url in `blabla` collection and if that url is not present then I am inserting that url. If it is present then I am just incrementing the number of views by 1.

It is suppose to give me only unique set of urls in the collection but I see some urls to be duplicated. What can be the reason of this duplication, is the insert task is not able to finish and it tries to find the same url and couldn't find?

Comment: what happens if you send two objects to your nodejs instance at the same time? Wouldnt that may mess it up?

Comment: also *loop* indicates that youre messing up sync/async code. May loop recursively... (please show that loop)

Comment: @Jonasw I have added the outer loop but what do you mean by sending two objects, its an if condition so I'm only doing one operation at a time

Comment: yep but may multiple users will visit your server at the same time...

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying, I'm trying to make it isolated from rest of the code. From this code I think it is making an asynch call to find and then it will insert, but meanwhile it is going to the next loop and not able to find the url as it has not finished insertion from the previous loop

Answer (score 1):

I would store the objects in a temp array, so youre resolving the multiple request problem. Then you can calmy iterate in the background:

```
var temp=[];
app.post(function(){
  //whatever
  //store in temp
  temp.splice(0,objects.length,...objects);
  addtoDatabase();//start the background process
 });
 function addtoDatabase(){
  var obj=temp.pop();
  if(obj){
     youraddtodatabasefunc().done(function(){
        if(temp.length) process.nextTick(addtoDatabase);
     });
  }
 }
```